# Can I install Windows 8 updates to a Windows 8 partition without being booted into Windows 8?

Tags: updates, windows-8-preview

I have a Windows 8 partition that was functioning perfectly since the second of this month. It recently gave me a BSOD and stopped working at all.

I tried the advice of everyone I could find that wanted to give it, except for one thing: installing updates.

I can boot into my Windows 7 partition but not into Windows 8. Can I install Windows 8 updates to a Windows 8 partition without being booted into Windows 8?

Comment: i'm confused; you can just reinstall from the same media you originally installed with. Is there something more that you want?

Comment: @Ian Boyd: My data is on the Windows 8 partition and I'd prefer not to have to go through the reinstall process.

Comment: Windows won't delete any personal data if you reinstall. You can also try to Windows 8 "Refresh my PC" option (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/01/04/refresh-and-reset-your-pc.aspx)

Comment: @Ian Boyd: I can't refresh my PC. It gives me an error when I try.

Comment: It says "There was a problem refreshing your PC. No changes were made".

Comment: So you think applying updates will make it function again? No, you cannot apply updates that way. Posting the entire bsod message might give us a clue to what happened and a possible resolution.

Comment: BSOD is 0xc000021a.

Comment: i hope that Microsoft got the beta feedback of the refresh failing. Still, reinstalling Windows will not delete files - which is the equivalent of doing a "reset my pc"

Comment: Can you make a Safe Mode boot? If yes... then you can use the Reset feature and instruct it to keep your personal data. If not, you can anyway access your stuff from Windows 7 and back up all your data and simply format and reinstall Windows 8.

Comment: @Corporate Geek: No, I can't boot into Safe Mode.